# cannot understand the difference between working and broken code

Tags: c++, c, pointers, posix

I need to initialize a Posix timer and I got it to work but kind of by miracle. I don't understand the difference between the working and the code the gives me segmentation fault.

This is the header of the create_timer function:

```
int timer_create(clockid_t clockid, struct sigevent *evp, timer_t *timerid);
```

Please tell me whats the difference between version 2 and 3?

Also, given that 3 works, how can version 1 even compile?

Clearly the 3rd argument to timer_create is different in v1 and v3 and yet they both compile..

This code fails: (but compiles)

```
main():
timer_t *tidlist;
tidlist = calloc(2, sizeof(timer_t));
initialize_timer(tidlist[0], 2);

int initialize_timer(timer_t *tid, int seconds){  
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, tid) == -1) <----- seg fault here. but it should not even compile because the working version accepts the **timer_t as argument.
```

this does not even compile: (even though its the exact same thing is the one that works)

```
main():
    timer_t *tidlist;
    tidlist = calloc(2, sizeof(timer_t));
    initialize_timer(tidlist[0], 2);//initilize timer for producer

initialize_timer(timer_t *tid, int seconds):
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &tid) == -1) <------- type error for 3 arg: incompatible pointer type.
```

*This code works:*

```
main():
    timer_t *tidlist;                                                  
    tidlist = calloc(2, sizeof(timer_t)); 
    initialize_timer(tidlist, 2);//initilize timer for producer

int initialize_timer(timer_t *tidlist, int seconds){
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &tidlist[0]) == -1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. You need to learn about pointers and arrays.  2. You need to turn up warnings in your compiler.

Comment: Successful compilation does not mean correct functionality. Ignoring warnings from your compiler is a bad idea.

Comment: there were no warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > Please tell me whats the difference between version 2 and 3?

   Version 2 has this line & definition:

   ```
   initialize_timer(timer_t *tid, int seconds):
       if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &tid) == -1)
   ```

   `tid` is a `timer_t *`, so `&tid` is a `timer_t **`, and that's not compatible with what `timer_create()` expects.

   Version 3 has:

   ```
   int initialize_timer(timer_t *tidlist, int seconds){
       if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &tidlist[0]) == -1)
   ```

   `tidlist` is a `timer_t *`, so `&tidlist[0]` is *also* a `timer_t *`, which is expected and works.  `&tidlist[0]` is equivalent to `tidlist`.
2. > Also, given that 3 works, how can version 1 even compile?

   Version 1 won't compile without warnings.  Heed them.  You have this code:

   ```
   timer_t *tidlist;
   tidlist = calloc(2, sizeof(timer_t));
   initialize_timer(tidlist[0], 2);
   ```

   `tidlist` is a `timer_t *`, so `tidlist[0]` is a `timer_t`, which isn't what `initialize_timer` expects.

Comment: for version one, it compiles without warnings

Comment: Then you don't have enough warnings turned on.

Comment: in version one, i chanded the line three in main() like this initialize_timer(&tidlist[0], 2); and now it work (i put the & in front of tidlist[0], so now it work perfectly.) so you thnk i have warning turned off? thats my makefile "all: gcc -ggdb -lrt -pthread -o jenia_thread thread.c bla bla bla". is that not the correct flags?